# No output for aws elasticbeanstalk in jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli, jenkins-groovy

I am not able to get any output from the following code in jenkins-pipeline.

```
sh'''
echo "Hello"
sh /var/lib/jenkins/devops-scripts/eb.sh
echo "End"
'''
```

when i manually ran the `eb.sh` in shell i am getting the output.

Here are the contents of `eb.sh`

```
envstaus=$(aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments 
         --environment-names test-environment 
         --query 'Environments[*].[Health]' --output text)
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that the commant output to stderr not to stdout?

You could easily check it with trying:
`command 2> /dev/null`
if it print nothing then:
`command 2>&1`
should help

Comment: `envstatus=$(aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names testEnvironment --region ap-south-1 --query \'Environments[*].[Health]\' --output text 2> /dev/null);` Can you tell wheather i am using it correctly or not

Comment: as long `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names testEnvironment --region ap-south-1 --query \'Environments[*].[Health]\' --output text` is what output what You want exactly in Your pipeline configuration, then yes.

Sometimes there could be "glitches" like some env behaviour differently than You think - i.e. the `env` vars could not be set (or rather, "cleaned" in spawned shell) for security reasons.

Comment: also, are You sure You want to use `(da)sh` (renamed in early 2000's)? maybe the shell version do not conform to some posix and You should try `bash` there?
DESCRIPTION
     dash is the standard command interpreter for the system.  The current
     version of dash is in the process of being changed to conform with the
     POSIX 1003.2 and 1003.2a specifications for the shell.